# IIS serving page remote but not locally

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I'm running:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5

I have only one site in IIS and for it I have next config:

- 2 site bindings

  - Type: http, Ip address: All unassigned, Port: 80, Hostname: example.com
  - Type: https, Ip address: all unassigned, Port: 443, Hostname: example.com (we use Certify ssl certificate)

I can access the site from any remote computer but if I logged in to windows server through RDP and open web browser (Firefox, or any other of course the browser doesn't matter), and type-in http://example.com or https://example.com it says no-connection.

What have I missed? Why is blocking the site from opening locally on the server? I have no rewrite rules.

If I add next binding, I can open the page by url: http://localhost

- Type: http, ip address: All unassigned, Port: 80, Hostname: **blank**

Comment: Assuming that example.com is resolving on the server to an external ip address, I suspect your router/firewall doesn't allow for NAT loopback. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run the diagnostics and the generated report should tell.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server have access to internet ? If no, then that's where its stuck. When you access http://example.com from the browser on your server, browser will still treat it to be a normal public facing site.

If you do not have internet connection and its still not working, do a ping to hostname from command prompt. If it fails, some component in your network is blocking internet traffic from the server and you should reach out to your networking team.

Lastly as a workaround, what you can do is add a "host" file entry - C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc as follows.

IP Address    example.com

For Example,
192.168.1.1   example.com

Let me know if you have any questions on this.

Comment: The server has access to the internet, I mean I can open any page with Firefox, Chrome ... google.com or something else. If that is what you mean